# Wordpress: Plugin for simple user profile pages

Tags: wordpress

In WordPress, I am aware that tld.com/author/username exists for authors, but I am looking for a public user profile page for non-authors. I want to setup a simplistic "favorite's list" for members on my site. Users will create an account, and add posts they like. They don't need access to wp-admin.

I'm looking for something simple like tld.com/user/username -- not /user/?uid=1. Nice and "pretty". Just like how WordPress handles /author/admin, or /author/username.

I would also like to keep /authors preserved so that's accessible too.

I have tried many plugins like WordPress-Users, but it's not a "pretty" URL, also have tried complicated plugins like Members, profile-builder, wp-user-frontend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to this from @bybloggers answer found here. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/58793/12920

I modified his code very slightly to tailor it to my needs, but this is the code that worked for me and was exactly what I was looking for:

```
// Create the query var so that WP catches the custom /member/username url
function userpage_rewrite_add_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'member';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'userpage_rewrite_add_var' );

// Create the rewrites
function userpage_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%member%', '([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^member/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?member=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init','userpage_rewrite_rule');

// Catch the URL and redirect it to a template file
function userpage_rewrite_catch() {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( array_key_exists( 'member', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {
        include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/user-profile.php');
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'userpage_rewrite_catch' );
```

After this was in my `functions.php` file, I had to re-save my Permalinks.

Sometimes re-saving the permalinks didn't finish the job 100% and browsing to www.mysite.com/member/username would 404, so I had to manually flush the rules by putting this into my `functions.php` and loading my site once. Then removing it so I don't run it every time the site loads, since that's unnecessary overhead.

```
// Code needed to finish the member page setup
function memberpage_rewrite() {
     global $wp_rewrite;
     $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init','author_rewrite');
```

Comment: There are better solutions to what you tried to accomplish other than restructuring your core WordPress files.  Now, when you update your WP, you'll have to recreate your files all over again -- or end up with a dinosaur version of WP in the future.

Comment: I'm all ears if you have a better way. This was the only way I found that wasn't a heavy plugin like Buddypress, or one with too many features like Wordpress Users. Also, with an upgrade, since this stuff is on init, won't it re-init the next time someone comes to the site?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you will find this one, at least not for free.  Have you checked out WPMU?  I started writing a membership plugin a few months ago but never completed it and am now doing it in Symfony.  Most WordPress membership plugins are either too complex to use or don't provide the features you need.

You should spec out what you need an get a local dveloper to build it for you, you might even be able to sell it if you do a good job.

Comment: Not sure it's such a stretch. WordPress Users is close. Non-pretty URL and lack of editing profile page have me a little sad. Given I have specific requirements, perhaps a code snippet using $_GET into my functions.php will do the trick?

Comment: Modifying a plugin is always fair.  You will have to reapply your changes if you upgrade it, so you should use a version control system.